# I can't deploy my mono application because o DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, mono

When I try to run my mono application using the following command:

```
mono SimpleBrowser.exe
```

I get the following error on my Mac:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception  was thrown by the type initializer for Gtk.Application ---> System.DllNotFoundException: glibsharpglue-2
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) GLib.Thread:glibsharp_g_thread_supported ()
  at GLib.Thread.get_Supported () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Gtk.Application..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at SimpleBrowser.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  [ERROR]
  FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Gtk.Application ---> System.DllNotFoundException: glibsharpglue-2
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) GLib.Thread:glibsharp_g_thread_supported ()
  at GLib.Thread.get_Supported () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Gtk.Application..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at SimpleBrowser.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I've tried searching for the missing glibsharpglue-2 library on my Mac but couldn't find it. I'm not sure what the problem is because the application runs when I launch it from Monodevelop.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set this environment variable before executing your app:

```bash
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib"
```

Since this is a pain to do every time you execute your app, you should create a wrapper script that does it for you:

```bash
#!/bin/bash 
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib"
mono SimpleBrowser.exe "$@"
```

This is just a minimal sample, here is a bit more advanced:

```bash
#!/bin/bash 
MONO_FRAMEWORK=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="$MONO_FRAMEWORK/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib"
EXE_DIR=`dirname $0`
$MONO_FRAMEWORK/mono $MONO_OPTIONS $EXE_DIR/SimpleBrowser.exe "$@"
```

And all you have to do is make sure the script is in the same directory as the executable to execute it. It allows allows you to pass options to mono (such as --debug for instance). This is usually how mono does it (`cat /usr/bin/mkbundle` for an example), and it's in the [offical Application Deployment Guidelines](http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Deployment).

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thanks.  Added the env to my .profile.

Comment: Thanks, though I needed `$MONO_FRAMEWORK/bin/mono` in the last line

Answer (score 0):

From a blog entry with a similar problem:  <strike>http://ngeor.net/blog/post/2012/08/25/Mac-and-Mono.aspx</strike> Edit: updated link:  http://ngeor.net/2012/08/mac-and-mono/

The problem here was with missing environment variables. I modified /etc/profile like this (the second and third line are supposed to be on the same line without the dots, I only broke it down to fit the page):

`export MONO_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="$MONO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/lib:...
...$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib"`

Comment: Where exactly is this /etc/profile file. The one I have has no statement like the ones shown above.

Comment: Is there a way to make these changes from within the MonoDevelop IDE itself?

Comment: Thanks, but monoMac was installed by default on my version. I can't edit the profile file because it's locked :/ Is there a way to get round that. Sorry, I'm very new to Mac development.

Comment: try `sudo open -a TextEdit /etc/profile `.  I don't actually use a mac

Comment: You can also do this in your `~/.profile` if you don't want to do this for all users.  The env vars are only required when you run from the command line, not inside the MonoDevelop IDE.

Comment: I tried that command line but I get an error: `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /etc/profile with error -10810.` There is no `~/.profile` on my mac.

Comment: The first link here is broken (so's the one in your comment).